# what is the function of "extend" syntax in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

i am new to lua. Recently i encounter a syntax call "extend" in lua, i look up the internet, but nothing can be found.

```
local item = require "item"
local object = item:extend()
```

I suspect it is related to inheritance, but no info online. Please help me to clear my doubt or point me to the right resource, thank you.

Comment: It's impossible to answer, as this doesn't come with standard Lua. Where does `item` module come from? This syntax mean: call a function stored as `extend` field in `item` table (or a userdata value) and pass `item` value as the first parameter (it's an equivalent to `item.extend(item)` call), but what exactly it does depends on the code of the `extend` function, which we don't know anything about.

Comment: extend() is just a function; item:extend() is syntactic sugar for item.extend(item). This is a comment because I am not sure if you're asking about what `extend` in particular means or if you think `:extend()` is some sort of special syntax taken as a whole (which it isn't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `extend` function in standard Lua. The `extend` function in your code snippet is a user-defined function coming from `item`. To know what it does, you'd need to look at the source code or documentation for it, not for Lua itself.